# CherryPy server running on windows gives random locking error

Tags: python, locking, cherrypy

I'm running a CherryPy server using file based sessions. When I run the server on my mac it works fine, but when I run it on a windows machine I have problems.

I have a web app that makes many GET requests (~50) to the server on page load. Often on one or more of those requests I'll get the below error message at the server. It doesn't happen with the same GET request each time, it seems random. Sometimes it loads without any problems at all.

```
14-07-2015 10:42:16 : INFO    : (CP Server Thread-81) : (_cplogging          ) : 127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jul/2015:10:42:16] "GET /static/scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js HTTP/1.1" 500 823 "http://127.0.0.1:8099/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36"
14-07-2015 10:42:16 : INFO    : (CP Server Thread-80) : (_cplogging          ) : 127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jul/2015:10:42:16] "GET /static/scripts/moment.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://127.0.0.1:8099/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36"
14-07-2015 10:42:16 : INFO    : (CP Server Thread-84) : (_cplogging          ) : 127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jul/2015:10:42:16] "GET /static/scripts/jquery.datetimepicker.js HTTP/1.1" 500 823 "http://127.0.0.1:8099/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36"
14-07-2015 10:42:16 : ERROR   : (CP Server Thread-81) : (_cplogging          ) : [14/Jul/2015:10:42:16]  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\lib\lockfile.py", line 127, in _unlock_file
    msvcrt.locking(self.fp.fileno(), msvcrt.LK_UNLCK, 1)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cprequest.py", line 104, in run
    hook()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cprequest.py", line 63, in __call__
    return self.callback(**self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\lib\sessions.py", line 797, in close
    sess.release_lock()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\lib\sessions.py", line 554, in release_lock
    self.lock.release()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\lib\lockfile.py", line 92, in release
    self._unlock_file()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\lib\lockfile.py", line 129, in _unlock_file
    raise UnlockError(self.fp.name)
cherrypy.lib.lockfile.UnlockError: Unable to unlock 'C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\my-project\\sessions\\session-3c95d3c281e1dff3fad8e059fa4115922262b390.lock'
14-07-2015 10:42:16 : ERROR   : (CP Server Thread-81) : (_cplogging          ) : [14/Jul/2015:10:42:16]  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\lib\lockfile.py", line 127, in _unlock_file
    msvcrt.locking(self.fp.fileno(), msvcrt.LK_UNLCK, 1)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cptree.py", line 144, in release_serving
    req.close()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cprequest.py", line 506, in close
    self.hooks.run('on_end_request')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cprequest.py", line 114, in run
    raise exc
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cprequest.py", line 104, in run
    hook()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cprequest.py", line 63, in __call__
    return self.callback(**self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\lib\sessions.py", line 797, in close
    sess.release_lock()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\lib\sessions.py", line 554, in release_lock
    self.lock.release()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\lib\lockfile.py", line 92, in release
    self._unlock_file()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\lib\lockfile.py", line 129, in _unlock_file
    raise UnlockError(self.fp.name)
cherrypy.lib.lockfile.UnlockError: Unable to unlock 'C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\my-project\\sessions\\session-3c95d3c281e1dff3fad8e059fa4115922262b390.lock'
14-07-2015 10:42:16 : ERROR   : (CP Server Thread-84) : (_cplogging          ) : [14/Jul/2015:10:42:16]  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\lib\lockfile.py", line 127, in _unlock_file
    msvcrt.locking(self.fp.fileno(), msvcrt.LK_UNLCK, 1)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cprequest.py", line 104, in run
    hook()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cprequest.py", line 63, in __call__
    return self.callback(**self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\lib\sessions.py", line 797, in close
    sess.release_lock()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\lib\sessions.py", line 554, in release_lock
    self.lock.release()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\lib\lockfile.py", line 92, in release
    self._unlock_file()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\lib\lockfile.py", line 129, in _unlock_file
    raise UnlockError(self.fp.name)
cherrypy.lib.lockfile.UnlockError: Unable to unlock 'C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\my-project\\sessions\\session-3c95d3c281e1dff3fad8e059fa4115922262b390.lock'
```

I've checked and 3c95d3c281e1dff3fad8e059fa4115922262b390 is the value of the cookie stored in the browser.

Any ideas why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: All I can say, with certain level of concurrency you may have issues on your Mac as well. As was discussed [in the group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/cherrypy-users/session$20lock/cherrypy-users/Q2voTWDez9o/lBSf13UgfvwJ) CherryPy file session locking is broken. It's not hard to suppose that Windows locking also has issues with high concurrency. For *nix it was fixed in [PR98](https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/pull-request/98)  but it's not there any time soon. In the meantime you can switch to memcached builtin backend or [cherrys](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cherrys).

Comment: Thanks for this. The only reason I wanted to use file sessions was so that if the server restarted then I wouldn't lose track of which sessions are active. I'll try and see if there is some way that I can periodically save the list of active sessions to a file, and then on load it will put those sessions into memory.

Comment: Redis is persistent by default, so you can go with [cherrys](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cherrys) as-is. However note, that if you run more than one CherryPy instance, you need to implement session locking in Redis or make sure you route users to instances consistently.